# Most efficient way to convert a Series of dicts to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Given data of the following form:

```py
ydata = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 3, 'd': 4}, None]
yindex = [50, 51, 52]
y = pd.Series(ydata, name='y', index=pd.Index(yindex, name='i'))
```

What's the most efficient, or even just the most idiomatic/preferred, way to convert this `y` Series to a DataFrame like the following?

```
      a    b    d
i                
50  1.0  2.0  NaN
51  3.0  NaN  4.0
52  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

One naive solution is:

```py
pd.DataFrame([rec if rec else {} for rec in y.tolist()],
             index=y.index)
```

Comment: `df=pd.DataFrame(ydata, index=yindex)` should do the trick

Comment: @BryceWayne I'm just constructing `y` for demonstration. The data is already coming to me from inside a column in a DataFrame.

Comment: I guess your solution should be good aproach here.

Comment: Try `pd.DataFrame(y.to_dict()).T ` PS this will fail if you have duplicate indices.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(v, index=[i]) for i,v in y.iteritems()])
print(df)
      a    b    d
50  1.0  2.0  NaN
51  3.0  NaN  4.0
52  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
d = y[y.notna()]
df = pd.DataFrame(d.tolist(), index=d.index).reindex(y.index)
```

Comment: This does look nice in that it uses lots of Pandas features. However it appears to be significantly slower than my naive list comprehension, at least on small toy data. Not sure how well the performance scales to larger number of rows. Let's see if other interesting answers come in.

Comment: @shadowtalker I think the duplicate answer `y.apply(pd.Series)` works for you. Interested to know which works faster.

Comment: I ended up going with my original solution because it seemed significantly faster than both.